# Is QFT nowadays only used for scattering processes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, scattering, education

I'm a fourth-year undergrad student who is interested in QFT but who thoroughly dislikes the field of scattering processes and related areas, and is then very confused as to what field to pursue a PhD in. My question is whether QFT is only used to study scattering and whether there is a subfield of physics (or more!) that uses QFT for other purposes.

Comment: In my experience, scattering amplitudes/perturbative QFT is less than 1/2 of the papers on QFT that are published every day. You can e.g. check the arxiv to get a taste of the things that are being done nowadays.

Comment: I think what you don't like is phenomenology (hep-ph). Like @AccidentalFourierTransform stated above, you should check arxiv for papers, particularly hep-th.

Answer (score 1):

If by scattering processes you mean particle scattering, then the answer is emphatically no. For example QFT is used for studying many body physics and condensed matter physics and is the reigning framework for studying phase transitions.